# BLE disconnects after BT pairing failed

Tags: qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

Linux Raspbian Jessie Lite, Bluez 5.40.
I have a GATT server and my own agent for incoming "standard" bluetooth connections (i.e. A2DP).

I can successfully "connect" to the GATT server, but if the user doesn't accept the pairing confirmation (from the BT) I receive this error:

> qt.bluetooth.bluez: Failed to create pairing "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply"

as expected, but after a couple of seconds also the BLE connection will drop.
I wonder if it's the correct behavior. I thought the BLE and BT connections are indipendent each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using two Bluetooth smart ready device(BR/EDR/LE), then the BLE connection would be over BR/EDR, so it is make sense that your BLE also disconnected.

Comment: Thanks, where I could find such an information in the official documentation? I mean: bluez, bluetooth stack, etc...

Comment: you can find them from Bluetooth core spec; however I was not remembered the detailed volume/section of it; i will update here after I get the clear information.